# database insert failure in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I'm trying to send my array values to the database. but there is a database problem error message. the message show - Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list' .  what problem in my code ?

from page:

```
 <form action="<?php echo base_url()?>Welcome/form_data" method="post">

<?php
$x=01;

for ($i = 0; $i <= 7; $i++) {  
    ?>

<label><?php echo $x++ ?>.</label>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo('L1' . rand(0, 10000000000) . 'MLM' . rand() . '00'); ?>" readonly="" name="screct_pin[]">
<input type="number" value="13<?php echo $x++ ?>5" name="user_id[]">
<br>


<?php }?>


<br>
<input type="submit">
```

Controller

```
public function form_data(){

    $this->WelcomeModel->form_data_info();
    redirect('Welcome');

}
```

Model:

```
public function form_data_info() {

    $data = array();
    $data['screct_pin'] = $this->input->post('screct_pin');
    $data['user_id'] = $this->input->post('user_id');

    $this->db->insert('tbl_pin',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are inserting array in value so, PHP cannot store array in column.
So here you need to go through each value in loop and insert value in database like below..

```
<?php

public function form_data_info() 
{

    $screct_pin_array = $this->input->post('screct_pin');
    $user_id_array = $this->input->post('user_id');
    for($i = 0; $i<= count($screct_pin_array); $i++)
    {
       $data = array();
       $data['screct_pin'] = $screct_pin_array[$i];
       $data['user_id'] = $user_id_array[$i];
       $this->db->insert('tbl_pin',$data);
    }   
} 

?>
```

Comment: Thankss. you made my day